# How to add external SSD over already existing HDD and boot Ubuntu through it

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, boot-partition

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on 500GB HDD, I want to upgrade it to boot through newly bought 120GB SSD. How shall I proceed to boot my Ubuntu on SSD rather than HDD and keep both drives as well. Do I need to install Ubuntu once again in SSD, what shall be the step by step procedure?

I also want the HDD to be auto mounted so I can have all the disk space seen when I browse through Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install Ubuntu again on the SSD. 
You don't have to wipe the HDD and use it as a Data storage with the help of fstab.

Once you install the SSD those are the following steps you will need to take to have the HDD mounted:

1. Find out the UUID of the HDD

   ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

This will give you and out put like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 27 08:11 4bfee3b6-b62e-4214-bfb8-507e5ab3d09b -> ../../sda1
```

The long number is your UUID so in my situation

```
bfee3b6-b62e-4214-bfb8-507e5ab3d09b
```

2. Create a mount location such as /Data

   mkdir /Data

3.Edit /etc/fstab to include your HDD

```
UUID=4bfee3b6-b62e-4214-bfb8-507e5ab3d09b       /Data       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
```

That should mount the disk for you on your next restart under /Data